# What became of the backup Doctor from Living Witness?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-eu, star-trek-emh

In the Voyager episode [Living Witness](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Living_Witness_%28episode%29) a backup copy of the Doctor sets off to follow Voyager's path, to see if they ever made it home. As this copy of the Doctor did not begin his pilgrimage until roughly 700 years after being separated from Voyager, I would imagine much of Voyager's trail would have been lost and forgotten to time. This would have made following Voyager's path very difficult, although ultimately the destination would be the alpha quadrant.

**Was it ever mentioned what became of this Doctor by anyone affiliated with the show? If there is no word-of-god fate for him, has his fate ever been brought up in anything else (books, etc)?**

Comment: Since it was an alternate future, I doubt it was revisited.

Comment: @ForceFlow It wasn't really an alternate future. It was just "700 years in the future" of the the Voyager setting.

Comment: Oh, from what I recalled, I thought it was a scenario where voyager *didn't* make it back to earth.

Comment: No, it really happened. Voyager accidentally left a backup copy of the Doctor on a planet. 700 years later that copy woke up in a museum and headed home. While chronologically the Doctor woke up centuries after Voyager got home, the episode broadcast well before they did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The EMH doctor activated in the Kyrian museum isn't mentioned in any further TV episodes or films.

There are, however a couple of fiction sources (non-canon) that relate to fate of the "Backup EMH"

- In [*Personal Log*](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Strange_New_Worlds_IV) by Kevin Killiany in *Strange New Worlds IV* (an anthology of short Trek stories) The Doctor encounters a number of species mentioned in the Voyager series including the Borg and the Hirogen. Basically by hiding from everything and drifting he eventually ends up back in the Alpha Quadrant.
- There is also a short fanfic called *The Witness* posted on [Robert Picardo's official website](https://web.archive.org/web/20170407151441/http://www.robertpicardo.net/fanfiction/witness.html) which relates to the Backup EMH's trip home. I won't spoil the ending for you, but be warned that it's a real tearjerker.

Answer (score 8):

When Q came aboard Voyager in Voy: [Death Wish](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/210.htm) he said humans would be in the Delta Quadrant in a few hundred years.

This means the Doctor wouldn't have had to go that far to run into a Starfleet ship.

> **QUINN:** *I, I'm not sure how. Humans. Humans. Who would have more recent experience with humans?*
>
> **Q:** *What have you done now, Q? Well, now, isn't this just fine.*
>   **Humans aren't supposed to be in this quadrant for another hundred years.**

Comment: Clever, but space is very very big and Q may have been referring to exploration vessels rather than a more substantial presence

Comment: This is a good point. And @Richard, even if it is only exploration vessels in 100 years, that gives the Federation and Star Fleet 600 more years to create some permanent colonies or outposts.

Answer (score -1):

It was not specifically mentioned in any episode after.  He stayed on the Kyrian planet for many years before leaving to follow voyager home.  I would like to think the cunning and resourceful hologram made it back; the last voyager crewmember to return home.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked. You might want to have a read of the Tour + FAQ; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour